# How to connect China region using Terraform azure providers

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am working currently for the china region portal. I am trying to automate the infra using Terraform. How to configure or connect the china region using Terraform providers.

I am going through harshicop document and found the below block.

environment - (Optional) The Cloud Environment which should be used. Possible values are public, usgovernment, german, and china. Defaults to public. This can also be sourced from the ARM_ENVIRONMENT Environment Variable.

but when I am passing it in the provider section. it gives the below error.

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: Hi, if your answer can solve your issue, you may consider accepting it. It will be helpful to other members who has the same issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  environment = "China" // Just added the environment  and its working fine.
  features {

  }
}
```

Comment: Why skip_provider_registration = true for China?